# jdeveloper weblogic wrong jar load

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x, jdeveloper

I'm working on a web application in java where I want to use ServletFileUpload class to upload my file. I've downloaded commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar and added that jar trough project properties. I'm using jdeveloper 11g and weblogic server.

When I run the application I get : "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: parseRequest".

here is my code:

```
List<FileItem> items;
items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
```

As I understand my application is probably using older version of the library.

My question is how do I make my application use this new library I've downloaded? Can I do it in though Jdeveloper or I have to change something on the server??

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the 'prefer-web-inf-classes' element in the weblogic-application.xml file to true. This then should load classed in the web-inf/lib folder befoer the ones defined in the server.

Read the [WebLogic classloading doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html) to get more info.

Comment: Timom thanks for the ansewer but it didn't work for me. I got this message afrer deploying the application: "weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: ....".

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was the problem. In my war file in WEB/lib I had two .jar files. commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar (which I added) and commons-fileupload.jar(this one was in Struts Runtime library). I excluded Struts Runtime from my project(because I didn't need it) and now It works fine.